# How execute a dynamic query in stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

I want to get from user variables: num for 'Top' clause and Tbl name from northwind DB,
and to get back result set of top 5, my script is down

```
create procedure sp_getTop5 
(
    @num int , 
    @tbl nvarchar(max)
)    
as       
    declare @res nvarchar(max);       
    set @res =  'select top '+str(@num)+' *   from '+@tbl

    exec @res   

---- check
exec sp_getTop5 5, employees
```

Comment: Great. Whats the problem?

Comment: Oh gods!!! That is just an injection issue waiting to happen. Why are you injecting an unsanitised **`nvarchar(MAX)`** into an `EXEC` statement?!

Comment: Also Top N without an ORDER BY may generate unexpected results

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wow... There's nothing else I can say other than that is one of the most terrifying dynamic statements I have ever seen. You're literally giving a malicious person access to 2GB worth of characters to inject with (*that's 1,073,741,824 characters with a `nvarchar(MAX)`*) against a statement that can easily suffer injection. They would ***LITERALLY*** be able to do anything they wanted with enough time (and permissions). Please take the time to read my article on [Dos and Don'ts of Dynamic SQL](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/dos-and-donts-of-dynamic-sql) and have a look at [Little Bobby Tables](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/Little_Bobby_Tables) to understand how dangerous what you have is.

As for your SQL, I don't care that you haven't really asked a question, you need to fix that massive hole in your security model now:

```
CREATE PROC getTop5 @Num int, @schema sysname, @table sysname AS --Removed sp_ prefix, see after the answer
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);
    SELECT @SQL = N'SELECT TOP (@Num) FROM ' + QUOTENAME(s.[name]) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(t.[name]) + N';'
    FROM sys.schemas s
         JOIN sys.tables t ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
    WHERE s.[name] = @schema
      AND t.[name] = @table;

    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@Num int', @Num;
END;
GO
```

Then you can execute it as below:

```
EXEC dbo.getTop5 5, N'dbo', N'YourTable';
```

This will (as a commenter just reminded me) give *N* arbitrary rows from the table (not the "Top" rows, and tables don't have an inbuilt order). So a `TOP` without an `ORDER BY` means the rows returned could be different *every* time the query is run.

As for my comment about the prefix: [Is the sp_ prefix still a no-no?](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix)